# AspectJ maven plugin with annotation processor - sources are generated twice

Tags: java, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour when combining the AspectJ compiler plugin with an annotation processor that generates sources.

I have **Project A**, the main project with annotated classes.

I have **Project B**, the dependency project with aspect classes and the annotation processor.

Ideally, what should happen, is upon compilation of project A, sources generated from annotated classes in Project A, using the annotation processor in project B should be compiled and saved in `target/generated-sources/annotations/...`

What actually happens is, upon compilation of project A, sources are generated in `target/generated-sources/annotations/...` and then generated a second time at the root of project A.

**Project A** pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ar.com.glamit.carriersShipmentRequest</groupId>
    <artifactId>carriersShipmentRequest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>carriersShipmentRequest</name>
    <url>http://www.glamit.com.ar</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.7</aspectj.version>
        <aspectjcompiler.version>1.8</aspectjcompiler.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>glamit-repo</id>
            <name>Glamit Repo</name>
            <url>http://nexus.glamit.com.ar/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.glamit</groupId>
            <artifactId>GlamitBootstrapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>jempbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmpbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>preflight</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configFiles>src/main/resources/flyway.conf</configFiles>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>migrate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <finalName>carriers-shipmentrequest</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>ar.com.glamit.carriersShipmentRequest.Entry</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>1.8</targetJdk>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>${pom.basedir}/pmd-exclude.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <excludeRoots>
                        <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources/</excludeRoot>
                    </excludeRoots>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>ar.com.glamit</groupId>
                            <artifactId>GlamitBootstrapper</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Project B** pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ar.com.glamit</groupId>
    <artifactId>GlamitBootstrapper</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.7</aspectj.version>
        <aspectjcompiler.version>1.8</aspectjcompiler.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>glamit-repo</id>
            <name>Glamit Repo</name>
            <url>http://nexus.glamit.com.ar/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-rc7</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.googlejavaformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-java-format</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.glamit</groupId>
            <artifactId>glamitrest</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.glamit</groupId>
            <artifactId>glamitworkers</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.glamit</groupId>
            <artifactId>glamitlogger</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.9-rc</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>1.8</targetJdk>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>${pom.basedir}/pmd-exclude.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <excludeRoots>
                        <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources/</excludeRoot>
                    </excludeRoots>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

A workaround I found for this is to add `<proc>none</proc>` under `<configuration>` of the AspectJ compiler, but it's just a workaround. Am I missing something?

I've also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022190/maven-aspectj-plugin-calls-the-jpa-model-generator-again) that seems to describe a similar issue.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but please update pdfbox to current.

Comment: This is interesting, but a rather complex situation. Please provide a minimal version of your situation which reproduces the problem. I know AspectJ and also Maven, but I do not feel so inclined to recreate everything from scratch, trying to guess what kind of annotation processor you have etc. Please publish an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, I can take a look then and share my insights with you, if any. With only the POMs I cannot answer the question.